# "memoryDataStore is not a constructor" error in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, store, slack-commands

I am starting slack development with node. 
Following a tutorial  I got an error message . I tried several  sources but I still cannot spot  my mistake

I am simply trying to print the bot 
and channel names

the version of node installed is 10 
however the examples are based on version 5

could that be the source of the error?

```
'use strict';

const RtmClient = require('@slack/client').RtmClient;


const MemoryDataStore = require('@slack/client').MemoryDataStore;


const RTM_EVENTS = require('@slack/client').RTM_EVENTS;

const CLIENT_EVENTS = require('@slack/client').CLIENT_EVENTS;

const token = 'myTokenGoesHere';


let slack = new RtmClient(token, {
logLevel: 'debug',


dataStore: new MemoryDataStore(),

autoReconnect: true,

autoMark: true});


slack.on(CLIENT_EVENTS.RTM.RTM_CONNECTION_OPENED, () => {
        // Get the user's name
        let user = slack.dataStore.getUserById(slack.activeUserId);
        // Get the team's name
        let team = slack.dataStore.getTeamById(slack.activeTeamId);
        // Log the slack team name and the bot's name, using ES6's
        // template
        // string syntax
        console.log(`Connected to ${team.name} as ${user.name}`);
    });
    // Start the login process
    slack.start();
```

I get this error message

```
> TypeError: MemoryDataStore is not a constructor
>     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ToughBook\appdir\index.js:33:16)
>     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)

    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:282:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

Comment: can you verify whether node module slack exists in your path.

Comment: Yes it exists - thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use version 2 of the slack client if you really want to follow the tutorials in the book by Paul.
Also, Visit https://your-workspace.slack.com/apps/new/bot-name to get API token but make sure you have a slack workspace already.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@slack/client": "^2.1.0"
  }
```